# MySQL select: replace parent_id column with name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of projects, where each can be a subproject of any other. Example table

```
mysql> select * from projects;

+----+-----------+------+
| id | parent_id | name |
+----+-----------+------+
|  1 |      NULL | foo  |
|  2 |      NULL | bar  |
|  3 |         2 | baz  |
+----+-----------+------+
```

I'd like to replace the second column (parent_id) with the name of the parent project, so in my case the 3rd row should become

```
|  3 | bar       | baz  |
+----+-----------+------+
```

What is the query for that?

Comment: I'm sorry but I disagree with the edit, as it's misleading, suggesting that the query should result in only one row. It should still result in 3 rows. So I changed it back, but left the bottom line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT A.id, B.name ParentName, A.name
FROM projects A
LEFT JOIN projects B
    ON A.parent_id = B.id
```

Comment: How can I accept this answer? It says `You can accept an answer in 6 minutes`

Comment: How can I open the door? A sign says 'push'.

Comment: @SzG No need to rush for accepting the answer (even though I appreciate the gesture), there is a time limit for that, I believe it's 15 minutes.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, it says that when I'm trying to push (click the empty check sign). :-)

Comment: @SzG Well, after the time limit, you can accept the answer. Anyway, there could be a better answer coming, so it's good that this time limit exists

Comment: @Lamak your answer seemed to be good enough after a quick test.